# CodeEffects - filter data source based on input parameter from other data source

Tags: rule-engine, business-rules, codeeffects

Is there any possibility to filter data source based on the selected item in another data source?

If it is possible please share some directions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is planned to be released in the next major version of Code Effects rules engine.